# quickblox sample video chat does not receives call when screen is off

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

i have to integrate video chat in my app and was trying Quickblox sample video chat but it does not receives call when screen is off. How can i make it able to receive ?

Answer (score 2):

Configure the following property for your activity in manifest file :

```
android:showOnLockScreen="true"
```

E.g.

```
<activity
            android:name="CallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"/>
```